# Are there routers available which allow to introduce latency and configure BER for testing

Tags: wireless

I am currently working on an application which is a client server based application. The client and server will be on a wireless network with limited bandwidth and both could be moving. I need to simulate latency and BER issues in order to test and ensure that my application's performance does not degrade too much.

I was wondering if there are any routers available which will allow me to introduce latency and also increase or reduce the BER. If anyone knows of such a router which I can buy from the market or a software which I can install to simulate this on LAN, please do answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try **netem** if your application running in Linux.
With it, You can simulate packet delay, loss, corruption .etc

Detailed information please refer:
http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem